# Fixing "widget annotation not nested inside a form structure element" in pdf

Tags: pdf, accessibility, acrobat

I have downloaded Free PDF Accessibility Checker:
https://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-accessibility-checker.html

When i use it to test a pdf i have, i get an error saying:
"Widget annotation not nested inside a form structure element"

I have an ordinary pdf document with a few fields where the user can type name, addresse, etc.

I do not understand what to change in my pdf to eliminate this error.

I use Adobe Acrobat DC Pro.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I do not know AADC. Where kan i find the repair tool og find the advice on how to build a form with accessible fields? I have looked at the developer-advice on the webpage where i downloaded the accessibility checker, but the advice on forms is only giving advice on html-forms.

Comment: I have used the accessibility checker in acrobat and the result is an error (translated from danish): "Tagged formularfields - failed". The error leads to this description: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html?trackingid=KACNN#TaggedFormFields Autotagging the form fields does not correct anything.

Comment: I will try asking in an Adobe Forum. Thanks for your contribution to this thread.